# I am not admin of my own itunes connect account

Tags: app-store-connect

I ran into a big problem and rite not I don't know how to solve it,
I have a apple developer account and I manage my users in iTunes connect.
Today I sent myself a request to be added as a tester to my own account.
But now when I login to my account I can't see myself as the admin and hence I can't add testers or do any other admin stuff.

I have tried contact us section of iTunes connect but there is no way I can submit my query to apple, I have looked in my developer account and there is not provision for doing so.

Comment: Have you contacted apple? I don't think it's the correct place here.

Comment: @Siddant Saxena have you solved your problem, we have also ran into same issue ?

Comment: @Siddhant Saxena Can you please provide some Information, its really urgent for me to solve this issue

Comment: Ya i contacted apple and they fixed the issue in a matter of 4-5 days.Thanks